# Previous shapefiles do not show in re-opened projects

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have previously drawn a lovely shapefile in a project - all saved...good job. I open the very same project and, although the background raster maps project fine, my shapefile will not show. Zooming to layer gets me to the origin point of the system - co-ordinates 0,0! I check the CRS and they are different for the shapefile vs the raster map. I change them to read the same. No change. I make sure "on the fly transformations" is checked - no change. I highlight the raster map and click "Set project CRS from layer" and I get a distorted background map and still no shapefile.

Help! Why is it so difficult? Is it possible to turn off CRS once it is set? I'm never going to change it again once it is working properly, and all this hassle will disappear!

Doug

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Could you please add which software and its version you are using?

Comment: (Use the **[edit]** button.)

Comment: What happens if you open QGIS, and add only the shapefile to a new blank project? Maybe you have forgotten to save shapefile **and** project.

Comment: Andre - no, the shapefile appears in the "layers" field so I'm pretty sure that means it is saved?

Comment: Martin F - What do I do with the edit button?! Doesn't seem to give me any relevant options. Ah - I see - use the edit button...yes.

Comment: Andre - just tried as you suggested anyway. No show. The CRS of the shapefile is EPSG:4326 - WGS 84. I've zoomed to this layer and absolutely nothing happens! No shift in background view or anything - it's as if it were filling exactly the bounds of the map projection but still not showing.

Comment: Slight amendment to earlier info - the background map is using this projection:  * Generated CRS (+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs) so I changed the shapefile CRS to match this in its properties menu. Still nothing happening. DOes my shapefile even exist, I wonder?!

Comment: "Change the shapefile CRS" is **evil**. This will demolish your data, because it does not reproject the coordinates to the new CRS. Rightclick on the layer and `Save As...`to a new filename and CRS is the only way to go.

Comment: OK - thanks Andre. I'll give it a go with a new shapefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shapefile exists, but it does not have any content.

If you create polygons, you toggle the edit mode with the pencil icon, and add new features.

If you have finished, you have to click on the Save icon next to the pencil (to save the layer content), **and** the save icon on the left (to save the project with all its layers).